# What is the appropriate verb for making a judicial decision to punish someone?

Tags: word-choice

Are punishments **inflicted** / **issued** / **administered** / or **delivered** by the court's judges? Is there any difference between these multiple alternatives (and probably others that I forgot), any nuances of meanings? Is any of them better than the others?

Comment: *Impose*, *pronounce*, *pass*, *hand down*, *give*, and, *deliver* are the most common verbs (in that order per the ngram viewer).

Comment: A judge will *adjudicate*.

Comment: A judge could adjudicate that the defendant is innocent, or an adjudication could be for a non-criminal case; so adjudication does not necessarily include punishment.

Answer (score 3):

An executioner/jailer *carries out*, *administers*, *delivers*, or *metes out* (past tense: *carried out*, *administered*, *delivered*, *meted out*) the punishment.

The judge *sentences* the defendant and *decides*, *sets* or *hands down* (past tense: *decided*, *set*, *handed down*) the punishment.

Answer (score 1):

Judges don't administer punishment. You could say that they

**assign a sentence**

**hand down a sentence**

**order community sentence**

etc

All those words you mention are different words so yes, there are differences between them.   Check a dictionary for more details.

Comment: *Assign* and *order* are vanishingly rare for the imposition of a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

***[Sentence](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sentence)***

> Declare the punishment decided for (an offender):
>   *'ten army officers were sentenced to life imprisonment'*
>
> **Origin**
>   Middle English (in the senses 'way of thinking, opinion',
>   'court's declaration of punishment', and 'gist (of a piece of
>   writing')): via Old French from Latin sententia 'opinion', from
>   sentire 'feel, be of the opinion'.

The court administers justice and passes judgement, which may be to sentence the guilty party, but in practical terms the punishment itself is usually *inflicted/administered/delivered/imposed* by the non-judicial arm. Judges don't like to be executioners...

Comment: In the US, what judges like or don't like is immaterial. The executive branch is the only branch allowed to carry out sentences. I don't think the verbs *inflict*, *administer*, or *deliver* are used for a judge's action in announcing a sentence. Do you have a cite for these?

Comment: @deadrat Chappo stated "the punishment itself is usually inflicted/administered/delivered/imposed by the ***non-judicial*** arm", i.e. **not** by judges, as you have said.